# Binary search tree in Python

Tags: python, tree

> Create a binary search tree representation of a given array of integers.

How can I improve this code?

```
# Creating Node object class
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

# Creating Tree class
class BST(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.root = Node(val)

    def insert(self, value):
        current = self.root
        while current:
            if value < current.value:
                if current.left == None:
                    current.left = Node(value)
                    break
                else:
                    current = current.left
            else:
                if current.right == None:
                    current.right = Node(value)
                    break
                else:
                    current = current.right


# inputs 
t = BST(22)
t.insert(30)
t.insert(10)
t.insert(80)
t.insert(90)
t.insert(9)
t.insert(23)
t.insert(14)
t.insert(6)
t.insert(40)
t.insert(60)
t.insert(3)
```

Comment: Improve in what way and sacrifying what for it? Each choice is a compromise. Are you seeking to use less CPU? less memory? less number of lines? reducing McCabe complexity? etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For checking whether something is `None`, use the `is` and `is not` operators in place of `==`.

<strike>You also do not need the `break` statements as the whole code is short circuited by `if-else` blocks.</strike> <sub>doesn't help because of a [logical error](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/191613/binary-search-tree-in-python/191624?noredirect=1#comment368023_191624)</sub>

Rewritten:

```
class BST(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.root = Node(val)

    def insert(self, value):
        current = self.root
        while current:
            if value < current.value:
                if current.left is None:
                    current.left = Node(value)
                    break
                else:
                    current = current.left
            else:
                if current.right is None:
                    current.right = Node(value)
                    break
                else:
                    current = current.right
```

At the end, you should use the [`if __name__` guard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5544752/1190388) for setting up the inputs/test section.

The rest all looks good.

Comment: This code is logically incorrect.. if you don't break out of the while loop after assigning `current.left` or `current.right`, it will execute forever.. Since in the next iteration, current will still have a value, so `while current` will evaluate True, and this time, it goes in the inner else block where current becomes the newly assigned node.. and so on

Comment: Hence downvoted..

Comment: @mu無 ah, yes. I did not think of that. Fixing it now!

Answer (score 3):

You can also consider a very elegant, recursive solution:

```
def insert(self, value, node=self.root):
   if node == null:
      return Node(value)
   if value < node.value:
      node.left = self.insert(value, node.left)
   else
      node.right = self.insert(value, node.right)
```

Although, please mind that in case of large trees, efficiency of that solution is slightly lower (because of call stack)

Answer (score 1):

There's some repetition, that @zlenyk exposed in his recursive answer that you can still use in your iterative answer:

```
def insert(self, value):
    current = self.root

    while current:
        if value < current.value:
           side = 'left'
        else:
           side = 'right'
        next = getattr(current, side, None)
        if next is None:
            setattr(current, side, Node(value))
        current = next
```

though it may be clearer as:

```
def insert(self, value):
    current = self.root

    def traverse(current, direction):
        next = getattr(current, side, None)
        if next is None:
            setattr(current, side, Node(value))
        return next

    while current:
        if value < current.value:
           traverse(current, 'left')
        else:
           traverse(current, 'right')
```

or maybe that last bit should be:

```
    while current:
        side = { True: 'left', False: 'right' }[value < current.value]
        traverse(current, side)
```

...or maybe not.  Your call, of course.  It depends on if you want to optimize for speed, maintenance, or cleverness ;)